# How to create a text file using php from the parameters passed to html page in url?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need my page *bargraph.html* to get parameters like `.../bargraph.html?di=xxxx&mn=yyyy` and save the values of `di` and `mn` using a php script in a text file named *cred.txt*. The code I'm using for *bargraph.html* is

```
<body>
    <?php
       $mobile_num = $_GET["mn"];
       $device_id = $_GET["di"];
       $file_name = "cred.txt";
       $location = "cred/".$file_name;
       $text = $mobile_num."\n".$mobile_num;
       $my_file = fopen($location, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
       fwrite($my_file, $text);
       echo "response submitted successfully!";
       fclose($my_file);
    ?>
</body>
```

The file named *cred.txt* is not created inside the *cred/* directory and neither I get any errors. What am I doing wrong?

If the same thing can be done using JavaScript I'll use that instead of php for this purpose.

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: You didn't specify what the problem is. Is the file being created where you expect? is it empty? do you get any errors?

Comment: no the file is not being created neither i am getting any error.

Comment: Did you look at the browser console for errors. Use the "developer tools" to see the errors.

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the php script, it's possible you don't have error reporting enabled

Comment: no error regarding php

Comment: i am using the same concept for creating files at other place but there iam using only single .php file for creation not .html

Comment: problem solved by changing the name to bargraph.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question references `bargraph.html` - presumably the php code that you have is NOT on that page but a separate script? If that is the case then if you were to use exception handling to try to track down the issue it might help. Also, I have always found better success when using full paths as opposed to relative ones

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['mn'], $_GET['di'] ) ){
        try{
            $filename='cred.txt';

            $mobile_num=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'mn', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $device_id=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'di', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            /*
                I have always found it is best to use a full path rather than relative
                Change `path/to/` to the appropriate path
            */
            $path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/cred';

            /* If the path does not exist, warn user */
            if( !realpath( $path ) ){
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Unable to find path: %s', $path ) );
            }

            /* Can the chosen directory be read? */
            if( is_readable( $path ) && is_writable( $path ) ){

                $file=$path . '/' . $filename;
                #$text=$mobile_num . PHP_EOL . $mobile_num . PHP_EOL;

                /* I think this is probably what you intended? */
                $text=$device_id . PHP_EOL . $mobile_num . PHP_EOL;

                $status=file_put_contents( $file, $text, FILE_APPEND | FILE_TEXT );
                throw new Exception( $status ? sprintf('All good! Saved %s',$file) : sprintf('Error - unable to save %s',$file) );

            } else {
                /*
                    should set permissions if reading/writing of target folder failed
                    chmod($path,0777); etc
                */
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'The path %s is either not readable or writable',$path ));
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
```

Using a plain HTML page you could send an ajax request to the above PHP script ( in code below called `bargraph.php` )

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ajax-store credentials</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='bg'>
            <input type='text' name='mn' id='mn' placeholder='Mobile number: eg 0141 353 3874' />
            <input type='text' name='di' id='di' placeholder='Device ID: eg yellow banana' />
            <input type='button' id='bttn' value='Go' />
        </form>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('bttn').onclick=function(e){

                var mn=document.getElementById('mn').value;
                var di=document.getElementById('di').value;
                if( mn != '' && di != '' ){
                    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload=function(r){
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=this.response;
                    };
                    xhr.onerror=function(r){
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=err.message;
                    };
                    xhr.open('GET','?mn='+mn+'&di='+di,true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.send();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id='status'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: php is not working inside the html page. may be the same thing can be achieved using javascript ??

Comment: If the page is called `bargraph.html` - note the `html` extension then it will not work unless you have done some trickery with your `.htaccess` file to force PHP to process HTML files as PHP. You can achieve the same thing using javascript ( ajax or fetch )

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
$mobile_num = $_GET["mn"];
$device_id = $_GET["di"];
$file_name = "cred.txt";
$path = getcwd();
$location = $path.'/cred/'.$file_name;
$text = $device_id."\n".$mobile_num;
$my_file = fopen($location, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($my_file, $text);
echo "response submitted successfully!";
fclose($my_file);
```

You need to give write permission on cred folder.

Comment: I was confused till I saw the `$path`

Comment: i have found that even echo is not working in php tag. i think the code is ok but problem is with the inclusion of php code in html page :/

Comment: How do you submit your values GET or POST and does your variables get echoed ?

Comment: values submitted using get. no echo is not working. i think javascript can be used for the same purpose but i don't know how to code in js

Comment: It will be help full if you post how you submit your data to the above code as well so we can make the middle connection.

Comment: if your file extension .html then **echo** not working you need to .php file for execute php code.